# Loading ListView in UI thread/AsyncThread

Tags: android

I have `ListView` in Android. The list contains elements that are loaded from database. In this situation it is recommended to loading data in `AsyncLoader`.

But, I don't load all elements at once. I rather load a ( for example ) 20 elements and I load next 20 `onScrollEvent`. So, it is not user-friendly to show a `ProgressDialog` ( I have to do it) when user `scroll`.

Is it allowed to do it from UI thread? How to solve it?

Comment: You shouldnt use AsyncLoader or any other of this stuff. Try using RXJava 2 since this handles your stuff + RecycleView which do the "chunkloading/caching" for you

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold No, he should absolutely be using AsyncLoaders and other concepts if they fit what he's doing.  RxJava is not a magic spell that works everywhere-  you have nowhere near enough knowledge of what he's trying to do to suggest it.

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold And RecyclerView does not handle loading for you.  It handles recycling.  If you're going for a recycler view where the backing store is fetched from network as needed, as seems obvious he's doing, RecyclerView does not tell you when to load new data from the network.  You need to figure that out.  Then you need to download it-  usually via a Loader.

Comment: Okay, got it. Anyway. RxJava is easy to use for this case. And it is recommend using this by several "high class developers" like jake wharton for EXACTLY those cases. Anyway, if another solution fits better, feel free to explain it. Learning is always great ;-)

Comment: @GabeSechan, I agree. The people often uses a things like RxJava and they don't know how it works. Gabe Sechan, please answer my question ( give pros and cons)

Comment: @EmanuelSeibold So because some other guy recommended using it for some other use case that may or may not be similar because you don't really have enough details, you suggest it here?  RxJava has its places, but it isn't pixie dust.  Saying "use rxJava instead of a loader" doesn't even make sense-  RxJava doesn't load data from a network.  At best you could say "launch a thread to download the data, then notify when you're done via RxJava", which is about all that library could do to help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main questions here are chunk size and where the database is.  If the database is remote, you'll obviously need to run an AsyncLoader of some sort.  If the database is local, and the number of items is small, you can probably get away with doing it on the UI thread.  Personally I wouldn't even do it onScrollEvent-  I'd use the getView of the Adapter.

```
  if (getCount() - position < CHUNK_SIZE) {
    //We're running low on items, lets get the next CHUNK_SIZE now
  }
```

If you do end up doing an asynchronous load, that check should also make sure there isn't an ongoing load in progress.  CHUNK_SIZE is kind of a guess-  too big and you'll waste bandwidth, too small and the user can scroll to the bottom.  You take a guess and adjust it.  It can even be adjusted dynamically based on network speed if you decide you care enough.

Comment: I would like to use better solution. I know that loading data from UI thread can be confusing, I don't what is cannonical solution. The database is local and I load nearly 20 elements at once.
Please tell me now what do you think.

"Personally I wouldn't even do it onScrollEvent- I'd use the getView of the Adapter.". Why?

Comment: Because onScrollEvent is called constantly.  If you scroll by even 1 pixel, its called.  Since most of the time you won't want to grab new items, its a bit of a waste.  And poorly performant code in onScrollEvent can be a real drag on the system.  getView is also called as you scroll, but much more rarely.

Comment: As for what thread-  given the small amount of data and that its coming locally, I'd grab it on the UI thread just for simplicity of not having to worry about race conditions and what to do if the activity got finished while you were loading.  I'd probably only move it to an asynchronous thread if I noticed drawing lag while scrolling.